# yt_dlp gives a strange message: "Seek to desired resync point failed. Seeking to earliest point available instead." and "File ended prematurely"

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, yt-dlp

I have a discord bot (discord.py) in python and it can play music. Lastly it had trouble in playing the music, giving some random warnings but it mostly worked. But now it gives me this message:

```
[matroska,webm @ 000001570fe92d40] Seek to desired resync point failed. Seeking to earliest point available instead.
```

```
[matroska,webm @ 000001570fe92d40] File ended prematurely
```

and also this one

```
Warning: program compiled against libxml 211 using older 209
```

As I saw this is a very common warning but I still have no Idea how to fix it.

I will leave the code of the bot down bellow:

Ytdlp setup *(I have renamed the librarie to be youtube_dl)*

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': True,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': False,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')
        self.duration = data.get('duration')
        img = ""
        imgs = ['']
        for image in data.get("thumbnails"):
            img = image["url"]
            imgs.append(image["url"])
        self.image = img
        self.thumbnails = imgs
```

The play command:

```
# if message.author.voice_client is not None:
try:
    print(1)
    sessionChannel = message.author.voice.channel
except:
    embedAns = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 201, 115))
    # embedImg.set_image(url=player.image)
    # embedImg.type = "image"
    embedAns.add_field(name="Player", value=f'To play audio you must join a voice channel!',
                       inline=True)
    embedAns.add_field(name="", value=f'*{message.author.name}*', inline=False)
    # embedImg.image.width = "800"
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedAns)
try:
    print(2)
    await message.author.voice.channel.connect(reconnect=False)
    print(2)
except:
    pass
"""embedAns = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(102, 196, 250))
# embedImg.set_image(url=player.image)
# embedImg.type = "image"
embedAns.add_field(name="Player", value=f'Succesfuly joined voice channel to play music in {sessionChannel}! Loading in youtube song... Please wait...', inline=True)
embedAns.add_field(name="", value=f'*{message.author.name}*', inline=False)
# embedImg.image.width = "800"
await message.channel.send(embed=embedAns)"""
try:
    print(3)
    load = await message.channel.send(
        f'Succesfuly joined voice channel to play music in {sessionChannel}')
    print(4)
    url = matched.group(1)
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop, stream=True)
    # Embed = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=client.loop, stream=False)
    sessionChannel.guild.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(
        f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)
    await load.delete()
    sec = player.duration % 60
    temp = player.duration // 60
    min = temp % 60
    hour = temp // 60
    if hour == 0:
        timeStr = f"{min:02d}:{sec:02d}"
    else:
        timeStr = f"{hour}:{min:02d}:{sec:02d}"
    # await message.reply()
    embedImg = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(102, 196, 250))
    # embedImg.set_image(url=player.image)
    # embedImg.type = "image"
    embedImg.set_thumbnail(url=player.image)
    embedImg.add_field(name="Player", value=f'Now playing: **{player.title}** \n `{timeStr}`',
                       inline=True)
    embedImg.add_field(name="", value=f'Requested by: {message.author.name}', inline=False)
    # embedImg.image.width = "800"
    await message.channel.send(embed=embedImg)
except Exception as ex:
    embedAns = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 119, 115))
    # embedImg.set_image(url=player.image)
    # embedImg.type = "image"
    # embedImg.set_thumbnail(url=player.image)
    embedAns.add_field(name="Player Error",
                       value=f'Couldent play audio on {sessionChannel} \n`{ex}`', inline=True)
    embedAns.add_field(name="", value=f'Requested by: {message.author.name}', inline=False)
```

Comment: I would assume, after a bit of researching, that it has something to do with your ffmpeg version try to update it and see if it works